# Scrapy/Splash Spider works randomly

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I have created a Crawler with Scrapy for a dynamic javascript website. Sometimes it works, sometimes it don't. This made wonder whether this was because of unstable internet maybe?

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
import csv
from time import sleep
import subprocess

wait_script = """
function main(splash)
  splash:set_user_agent(splash.args.ua)
  assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
  
  -- requires Splash 2.3
  splash:wait(5)
  -- while not splash:select('.shelfProductTile-descriptionLink') do
    splash:wait(1)
  end
  return {html=splash:html()}
end
"""

class IceTeaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "icetea"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = "<my-url>"
        yield SplashRequest(url, args={
            'lua_source': wait_script,
            })

    def parse(self, response):
        breadcrumbs = response.xpath(
            '//*[@id="search-content"]/div/shared-breadcrumb/div/ul'
        )
        products = response.css("a.shelfProductTile-descriptionLink::text").getall()
        
        for html in breadcrumbs:
            yield {
                "category": html.css("a.ng-star-inserted::text").getall()
                + html.css("span.ng-star-inserted::text").getall(),
                "products": products,
            }
            with open('breadcrumbs_result.csv', 'w') as f:
                write = csv.writer(f)
                write.writerows([['Results'], [str(html.css("a.ng-star-inserted::text").getall())]])

            with open('products_result.csv', 'w') as f:
                write = csv.writer(f)
                write.writerow(['Product Name'])
                write.writerows([products])
```

Is there something simple I can do like checking whether products returns an object, if not maybe I execute the crawler again? Or am I missing something?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: If it's not working it's more than likely you have to increase the timer on the lua script or download delay for scrapy